# Create spec HTML Table using PHP stdClass Object

Tags: php, html, arrays, oop

I have an array of date, something like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [question_id] => 64
        [title] => Question1
        [question_type_id] => 1
        [settings] => 
        [poll_id] => 5
        [answer] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [answer_id] => 1
                        [poll_id] => 5
                        [question_id] => 64
                        [answer] => Answer1-1
                        [created_at] => 2018-07-08 17:36:15
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [answer_id] => 5
                        [poll_id] => 5
                        [question_id] => 64
                        [answer] => Answer1-2
                        [created_at] => 2018-07-08 19:27:33
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [question_id] => 65
        [title] => Question2
        [question_type_id] => 6
        [settings] => ["više od 2km","manje od 2km"]
        [poll_id] => 5
        [answer] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [answer_id] => 2
                        [poll_id] => 5
                        [question_id] => 65
                        [answer] => Answer2-1
                        [created_at] => 2018-07-08 17:36:47
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [answer_id] => 6
                        [poll_id] => 5
                        [question_id] => 65
                        [answer] => Answer2-2
                        [created_at] => 2018-07-09 23:31:31
                    )

            )

    )
```

I need a table in browser to look like
enter image description here

```
Question1   Question2   Question3
Answer1-1   Answer2-1   Answer3-1
Answer1-2   Answer2-2   Answer3-2
```

This is my code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($DATA['question'] as $question): ?>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($question->title); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <?php foreach ($DATA['question'] as $question): ?>
        <td><?php for ($i=0,$j=count((array)$question->answer);$i<$j;$i++) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($question->answer[$i]->answer);
            }?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My problem is that I can not place Answer1-2 in the next row of table.
Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options how you can do this.

- Generate each of your intended columns as a single element and place that in a cell.
- Populate an array in the way you wish to display them
- Create a `for(i=0;i<maxAmountOfAnswers;i++)` wrapping another `foreach` (questions) and populate the table row by row.
- Use DataTables or other libraries that can read a json.

Think about why you want this though; semantically tables are intended to display one kind of data. Is there a good reason why you wouldn't just show 1 table per question, or tables at all?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer! It is my solutionn.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($DATA['question'] as $question): ?>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($question->title); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <?php foreach ($DATA['question'] as $question): ?>
        <td><?php for ($i=0,$j=count((array)$question->answer);$i<$j;$i++) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($question->answer[$i]->answer);
            echo "<br />";
            }?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And what is looks like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXAPt.png)